# AWS - Search all faces in an image against collection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

SearchFacesByImage API takes only the the largest face in the image and searches against the collectionId. I want to search all the faces in the input image against the collectionId

On the API of SearchFacesByImage It's write: "To search for all faces in an input image, you might first call the operation, and then use the face IDs returned in subsequent calls to the operation."
But i don't understand what i have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are reading appears to have a missing function name.

For example, the boto3 documentation for [`search_faces_by_image()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.search_faces_by_image) reads exactly as you have quoted.

Fortunately, the official [`SearchFacesByImage` API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFacesByImage.html) has the full text of the paragraph:

> To search for all faces in an input image, you might first call the `IndexFaces` operation, and then use the face IDs returned in subsequent calls to the `SearchFaces` operation.

This makes a lot more sense!

It is saying that you could call `IndexFaces` to convert multiple faces in an image into a list of Face IDs. Then, you could loop through each of those Face IDs and call `SearchFaces`, passing in the Face ID.

Comment: Thanks !, I have understand i will try it